# HP EliteBook 2560p - Windows 10, Windows Hello

Tags: windows, windows-10, fingerprint

I got a quick question. I have this laptop with Windows 10 x64, with all drivers installed (biometrics are detected normally in Device Manager) but I still can't set up Windows Hello, it just doesn't appear in the Sign-In settings.

I tried getting it to work for hours to no avail, does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the requirements of Windows Hello [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications)

> Windows Hello requires specialized illuminated infrared camera for
>   facial recognition or iris detection, or a finger print reader which
>   supports the Window Biometric Framework. Windows Hello with an Intel®
>   RealSense™ (F200) camera requires a software update to work on Windows
>   8.1 devices after upgrading to Windows 10. This update is expected to be available soon.

It's more than possible that your current fingerprint reader does not support the Windows Biometric Framework. Additionally, it won't work with just any webcam, if that's the option you were hoping to enable.

Comment: I see, so this fingerprint reader probably doesn't support WBF... That's kinda dumb, since HP Security Manager doesn't work on Wnidows 10 as well.